# ASA stopped working suddenly

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

My ASA 5516 stopped working all for sudden. There was no In/Outbound traffic anymore, Ping to the inside and outside interface failed.

Before the device was running for more then 6 months.

At the problem time there was only drop messages recorded in syslog, like:

```
Jun 29 08:55:48 192.168.100.1 %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 2 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 13 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 7913,2018-06-29T08:55:48.000+0200
Jun 29 08:56:08 192.168.100.1 %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 2 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 13 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 7876,2018-06-29T08:56:08.000+0200
Jun 29 08:56:29 192.168.100.1 %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 3 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 12 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 7759,2018-06-29T08:56:29.000+0200
Jun 29 08:56:49 192.168.100.1 %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 2 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 12 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 7709,2018-06-29T08:56:49.000+0200
Jun 29 08:57:09 192.168.100.1 %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 2 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 12 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 7606,2018-06-29T08:57:09.000+0200
Jun 29 08:57:09 192.168.100.1 %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-2 exceeded. Current burst rate is 0 per second, max configured rate is 8; Current average rate is 10 per second, max configured rate is 4; Cumulative total count is 36538,2018-06-29T08:57:09.000+0200
Jun 29 08:57:29 192.168.100.1 %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 3 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 12 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 7504,2018-06-29T08:57:29.000+0200
Jun 29 08:57:49 192.168.100.1 %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 2 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 12 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 7417,2018-06-29T08:57:49.000+0200
Jun 29 08:58:09 192.168.100.1 %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 3 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 12 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 7308,2018-06-29T08:58:09.000+0200
Jun 29 08:58:29 192.168.100.1 %ASA-4-733100: [ Scanning] drop rate-1 exceeded. Current burst rate is 3 per second, max configured rate is 10; Current average rate is 12 per second, max configured rate is 5; Cumulative total count is 7235,2018-06-29T08:58:29.000+0200
```

One more suspicious message but this goes on since months

```
Jun 29 09:02:38 192.168.100.1 %ASA-3-341011: Storage device with serial number MSA2101XXXX in bay 0 faulty
```

I was able to get onto the device via the serial interface, at the downtime i've checked the ARP cache for the default gateway - the record was valid.

During the reload there was this message appearing:

```
 Jun 29 10:09:50 192.168.100.1 %ASA-3-341008: Storage device not found. Auto-boot of module sfr cancelled.  Install drive and reload to try again.
```

Not sure but is it possible that the storage device can cause this?

What would you recommend to do or what would you try if this happens again?

Thx
Matt

```
xx-xx-asa01# show ver

Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Software Version 9.7(1)
Firepower Extensible Operating System Version 2.1(1.66)
Device Manager Version 7.7(1)

Compiled on Mon 16-Jan-17 09:00 PST by builders
System image file is disk0:/asa971-lfbff-k8.SPA
Config file at boot was "startup-config"

xx-xx-asa01 up 3 days 4 hours

Hardware:   ASA5516, 8192 MB RAM, CPU Atom C2000 series 2416 MHz, 1 CPU (8 cores)
Internal ATA Compact Flash, 8000MB
BIOS Flash M25P64 @ 0xfed01000, 16384KB

Encryption hardware device : Cisco ASA Crypto on-board accelerator (revision 0x1)
                             Number of accelerators: 1

 1: Ext: GigabitEthernet1/1  : address is 70db.989d.bf2e, irq 255
 2: Ext: GigabitEthernet1/2  : address is 70db.989d.bf2f, irq 255
 3: Ext: GigabitEthernet1/3  : address is 70db.989d.bf30, irq 255
 4: Ext: GigabitEthernet1/4  : address is 70db.989d.bf31, irq 255
 5: Ext: GigabitEthernet1/5  : address is 70db.989d.bf32, irq 255
 6: Ext: GigabitEthernet1/6  : address is 70db.989d.bf33, irq 255
 7: Ext: GigabitEthernet1/7  : address is 70db.989d.bf34, irq 255
 8: Ext: GigabitEthernet1/8  : address is 70db.989d.bf35, irq 255
 9: Int: Internal-Data1/1    : address is 70db.989d.bf2d, irq 255
10: Int: Internal-Data1/2    : address is 0000.0001.0002, irq 0
11: Int: Internal-Control1/1 : address is 0000.0001.0001, irq 0
12: Int: Internal-Data1/3    : address is 0000.0001.0003, irq 0
13: Ext: Management1/1       : address is 70db.989d.bf2d, irq 0
14: Int: Internal-Data1/4    : address is 0000.0100.0001, irq 0

Licensed features for this platform:
Maximum Physical Interfaces       : Unlimited      perpetual
Maximum VLANs                     : 150            perpetual
Inside Hosts                      : Unlimited      perpetual
Failover                          : Active/Active  perpetual
Encryption-DES                    : Enabled        perpetual
Encryption-3DES-AES               : Enabled        perpetual
Security Contexts                 : 2              perpetual
Carrier                           : Disabled       perpetual
AnyConnect Premium Peers          : 4              perpetual
AnyConnect Essentials             : Disabled       perpetual
Other VPN Peers                   : 300            perpetual
Total VPN Peers                   : 300            perpetual
AnyConnect for Mobile             : Disabled       perpetual
AnyConnect for Cisco VPN Phone    : Disabled       perpetual
Advanced Endpoint Assessment      : Disabled       perpetual
Shared License                    : Disabled       perpetual
Total TLS Proxy Sessions          : 1000           perpetual
Botnet Traffic Filter             : Disabled       perpetual
Cluster                           : Enabled        perpetual
Cluster Members                   : 2              perpetual
VPN Load Balancing                : Enabled        perpetual

Serial Number: xx
Running Permanent Activation Key: 0xxxx 0xxxx 0xxxx 0xxxx 0xxxx
Configuration register is 0x10001
Image type                : Release
Key Version               : A
Configuration has not been modified since last system restart.
```

Comment: According to Cisco, you have a hard drive failure.   I'd call TAC if you have a service contract.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ron Trunk is correct. Your internal SSD has failed (with serial number MSA2101XXXX). Your ASA likely has a MPF "policy" that is sending traffic to the SFR module with the **fail-closed** option. Thus no traffic.

Remove the policy and do as Ron said and call TAC.